# SQL Split Single Row into Fixed Number of Columns

Tags: sql

We need to split a single row into fixed number of multiple columns. Following is an example for the data set:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

Desired Output:

```
Column A        Column B       Column C      Column D
1                  2              3              4
5                  6              7             NULL
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: which database are you using @HankG?

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server Solution:**

**Create Sample Table:**

```
create table mytable (col1 int)

insert into mytable values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7);
```

Using [**Modulo**](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/examples-modulo-operator-225.aspx) and [**Row_Number()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), you could easily do this:

**Modulo Query:**

```
SELECT 
    R1.col1 as columnA,
    R2.col1 as columnB,
    R3.col1 as columnC,
    R4.col1 as columnD
FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS RowNum, col1 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE 
            col1 % 4 = 1
    ) AS R1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS RowNum, col1 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE 
            col1 % 4 = 2
    ) AS R2
    ON R1.RowNum = R2.RowNum
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS RowNum, col1 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE 
            col1 % 4 = 3
   ) AS R3
    ON R2.RowNum = R3.RowNum
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS RowNum, col1 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE 
            col1 % 4 = 0
   ) AS R4
    ON R4.RowNum = R3.RowNum
```

**Result:**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |       3 | 4       |
|       5 |       6 |       7 | (null)  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0077a/1/0)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome! Please close this question by accepting the answer above. Thanks!